# NULL Value representations

Tags: sql

Can someone tell me how `NULL` values represented in a database.I assume that most databases must be using the same representation for `NULL` values.If not so, can you tell me about atleast one implementation.

I have googled this without much success.

Comment: You might want to [check this out](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/09/06/How_does_SQL_Server_really_store_NULL-s.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume that most databases must be using the same representation for NULL values.

I wouldn't assume this, since database people put a lot of thought into how to make layouts (and everything else) as efficient as possible. There's a good chance one of them came to a different opinion to the others.

I know both SQLServer and PostgreSQL use a null bitmap per row. I know it's optional in PostgreSQL - so skipped entirely if there are no nullable fields, and don't know if that's the case with SQLServer.

So, e.g. a ten-column row with the 3rd and 9th fields being null could have a bitmap entry of `0000000100000100` = `0x0103`. Or maybe it'd be the other way around (`0010000010000000` = `0x2080`) , I honestly don't know.

I wouldn't assume it was true of any other database though.

Answer (score 0):

why do u need "NULL" ?
Better don't use it since querying could be messed up.

did you try this one ?
http://databases.about.com/cs/sql/a/aa042803a.htm

Comment: Actually i want to know about its representation in sql.I am trying to study implemetation of different databases in detail.

Comment: It's also silly to say you'd better not use null. If you need null, and don't use null, you'll end up with a bizarre and convoluted attempt to represent null.

Comment: with better don't use i meant avoid it. Sure if you need it use it.